# Why does this query need variables if it's pulling from a duplicated table?

Tags: sql-server

```
USE AP
SELECT * INTO #InvoiceCopy FROM Invoices
DECLARE @InvoiceID int, @InvoiceTotal money
DECLARE @Total money
SET @Total = 0
WHILE @Total + (SELECT TOP 1 InvoiceTotal
 FROM #InvoiceCopy
 ORDER BY InvoiceTotal DESC) <= 200000
 BEGIN
 SELECT TOP 1 @InvoiceID = InvoiceID, @InvoiceTotal = InvoiceTotal
 FROM #InvoiceCopy
 ORDER BY InvoiceTotal DESC
 IF @InvoiceTotal < 1000
 BREAK
 ELSE
 BEGIN
 SET @Total = @Total + @InvoiceTotal
 DELETE FROM #InvoiceCopy
 WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID
 END
 END
PRINT 'Total: $' + CONVERT(varchar, @Total, 1)
```

This is from a test study guide.

What was the purpose in creating the invoiceID and invoiceTotal variables when a duplicate table was already made? Would it not make more sense to just select the columns from the duplicate table?

Also,

SET @Total = @Total + @InvoiceTotal
 DELETE FROM #InvoiceCopy
 WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID
 END

I'm assuming this is deleting invoices that are less than 1,000 from the table. However, I don't understand how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs those variables to track where it is in the loop

```
USE AP
SELECT * INTO #InvoiceCopy FROM Invoices  --make a temp table to do calculations with
DECLARE @InvoiceID int, @InvoiceTotal money 
DECLARE @Total money
SET @Total = 0 

-- Loop while @Total plus the biggest total in the temp table is less than 200000
WHILE @Total + (SELECT TOP 1 InvoiceTotal 
                FROM #InvoiceCopy
                ORDER BY InvoiceTotal DESC) <= 200000
 BEGIN
     SELECT TOP 1 @InvoiceID = InvoiceID, @InvoiceTotal = InvoiceTotal
     FROM #InvoiceCopy
     ORDER BY InvoiceTotal DESC

    -- if the InvoiceTotal is less than 1000 then stop looping
    IF @InvoiceTotal < 1000
         BREAK
    --if it's >= 1000 then do this
    ELSE
        BEGIN
           -- Assign the current @Total plus @InvoiceTotal to the @Total variable
           SET @Total = @Total + @InvoiceTotal
           -- Remove that @InvoiceID from the temp table
           DELETE FROM #InvoiceCopy
           WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID
        END
 END
PRINT 'Total: $' + CONVERT(varchar, @Total, 1)
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh GOTCHA!